# PHP preg_replace regex question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need some help figuring out an regular expression. In my script I have a certain line with placeholders. What I want to do is I want to send every placeholder text a an function that translates it to what it should be.

E.g. my text is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit **{{AMETPLACEHOLDER}}**,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit.

I want the text **AMETPLACEHOLDER** to be send of to my function `translateMe`.

I am really bad in regex but gave it a try anyways. I don't get further than this:

```
$sString    = preg_replace("(*.?)/\{{(*.?)}}(*.?)/", $this->echoText('\\2'), $sString);
```

Which off course doesn't work.

Can anybody help me out?

Br,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), you can specify a method like this:

```
 = preg_replace_callback("@{{(.*?)}}@", array($this, "echoText"), $txt)
```

And the method could be:

```
 public function echoText($match) {
     list($original, $placeholder) = $match;   // extract match groups
     ...
     return $translated;
 }
```

Btw, for designing regular expressions check out http://regular-expressions.info/ or some of the tools listed in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: Thnx. It worked perfectly. When I get the time I'll check your links out. Should really get going with regex.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use either the `/e` modifier to parse the replacement to `eval`, or use [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

eg.

```
$sString = preg_replace("#\{\{(*.?)\}\}#e", 'echoText("$2")', $sString);
```

But the `$this` will cause problems there, if you are using 5.3+ you could use a closure to create a function to cope with that, or create a callback:

```
$sString = preg_replace_callback("#\{\{(*.?)\}\}#", array($this, 'echoText'), $sString);
```

`$this->echoText()` would have to be modified to catch the match array rather than the string in that case.

Or with an anonymous function:

```
$sString = preg_replace_callback("#\{\{(*.?)\}\}#", function ($matches) {
               return $this->echoText($matches[1]);
           }, $sString);
```